# How to add datetime formate for public function as key(stdClass) in controller/laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, chart.js

so I'm trying to get data for my chart from the database and I want it to display a number of orders per day scenario well I tried this code and it gives me full unformatted dates from the database. Any ideas on how to change it to date/month??

```
    $data = DB::table('analytics')->get();
    $attrs = array();




    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

        
        // -> as it return std object
        $attrs[$value->created_at][] = $value->order;
    }

    


    // dd($attrs);

    return view('analytic::dashboard.test', compact('attrs'));
```

Comment: can you provide expected attrs output ?

Comment: array like this {"2021-05-01 11:11:14":["343"],"2021-05-02 00:00:00":["371"]} @JohnLobo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$value->created_at` is a full date/time string. Since you want to organize it by dates, then you'll need to format it first. Thankfully, Laravel's timestamps are automatically converted to Carbon, so it's easy to format

```
$attrs[$value->created_at->toDateString()][] = $value->order;
```

If you want just the year/month, then use `format()` instead

```
$attrs[$value->created_at->format('Y-m')][] = $value->order;
```

**Edit** I see now you're using query builder (DB), not Eloquent, so you'll need to actually parse the timestamp separately.

```
$date = Carbon::create($value->created_at);
$attrs[$date->toDateString()][] = $value->order; // 2021-07-14
$attrs[$date->format('Y-m')][] = $value->order;  // 2021-07
```

Comment: it returned with error "Call to a member function format() on string"

Comment: Oh! I thought you were using Eloquent, but you're using query builder. Let me adjust that.

Comment: No worries and yes even this code I found it online as I need the values based on dates so I can call it to view for the chart.js

Answer (score 0):

If you are using collection then

```
 $user=DB::table('analytics')->get()
                            ->mapToDictionary(function ($analytics){
                                $date=Carbon::parse($analytics->created_at)->format('d-m-Y');
                                $data[$date]=$analytics->order;
                                return $data;
                             })->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use Eloquent instead of the DB query builder. If you have an `Analytic` model, then this is quite simple. You could just add `created_at` to your `$dates` array and it will automatically be cast as a `Carbon` instance. For instance, in your model:

```
protected $dates = ['created_at'];
```